# jQuery - even.keyCode not being recognized correctly in firefox?

Tags: jquery, events, firefox, live, keycode

the code below works properly in IE and Chrome (latest versions)

```
$('#searchBox').keyup(function () {
    var searchTxt = $(this).val();

    // if item contains searchTxt,
    if ($('.item:contains("' + searchTxt + '")')) {
        // hide the items that do NOT contain searchTxt
        $('.item').not(':contains(' + searchTxt + ')').hide();
    };

    // capture backspace
    if (event.keyCode == 8) {
        // show item that contains searchTxt
        $('.item:contains(' + searchTxt + ')').show();
    };

    // if search box is empty, 
    if ($('#searchBox').val() == "") {
        // show all items
        $('.item').show();
    };
});
```

the code above performs a "case sensitive live search" and fails to execute the chunk of code that captures the backspace key in firefox:

```
// capture backspace
if (event.keyCode == 8) {
    // show item that contains searchTxt
    $('.item:contains(' + searchTxt + ')').show();
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put `event` argument in:

`$('#searchBox').keyup(function (event) { .. })`;

and instead of `keyCode` user `event.which`.

Read more about ***[event.which](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/)***

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the event object.

```
$('#searchBox').keyup(function (event) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the event in the function like this:

```
$('#searchBox').keyup(function (event) {

});
```